# Mocha test not working with Typescript namespace and triple slash import

Tags: typescript, mocha.js

I'm trying to run tests on my Typescript file `validators/validators.ts`:

```
declare function require(arg: string): any;

namespace Validator {
    export function hello() {
        return 'Hello World!';
    }
}
```

The test file is `src/test.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="../validators/validators.ts" />

const expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('Hello function', () => {
    it('should return hello world', () => {
        const result = Validator.hello();
        expect(result).to.equal('Hello World!');
    });
});
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2015",
    "module": "system",
    "outFile": "test.js"
  },
  "include": [
    "./*",
  ]
}
```

Running `tsc` outputs `test.js`:

```
var Validator;
(function (Validator) {
    function hello() {
        return 'Hello World!';
    }
    Validator.hello = hello;
})(Validator || (Validator = {}));
/// <reference path="../validators/validators.ts" />
const expect = require('chai').expect;
describe('Hello function', () => {
    it('should return hello world', () => {
        const result = Validator.hello();
        expect(result).to.equal('Hello World!');
    });
});
```

Running `npm test` FAILS:

```
  Hello function
    1) should return hello world


  0 passing (6ms)
  1 failing

  1) Hello function
       should return hello world:
     ReferenceError: Validator is not defined
      at Context.it (src/test.ts:7:24)
```

package.json is simply:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha src/**/test.ts"
  }
}
```

`npm version` output:

```
{ npm: '5.5.1',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  cldr: '31.0.1',
  http_parser: '2.7.0',
  icu: '59.1',
  modules: '57',
  nghttp2: '1.25.0',
  node: '8.9.0',
  openssl: '1.0.2l',
  tz: '2017b',
  unicode: '9.0',
  uv: '1.15.0',
  v8: '6.1.534.46',
  zlib: '1.2.11' }
```

What am I doing wrong on the namespace import that is causing this?

Comment: What's the shell command that `npm run test` resolves to?

Comment: Added package.json above (it's in the parent directory of "src" and "validators")... it's simply "mocha".  FYI, I'm manually running "tsc" in "src" prior to running "npm test".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `mocha` on the compiled file (presumably `src/**/*.test.js`) instead of the raw TypeScript files (`src/**/test.ts`). When `mocha` runs on `test.ts`, `Validator` is not defined in the test because it's defined in a different file.

Comment: Yep.  Thanks.  Stupid mistake on my part.